# Don't include word in negative look ahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't want to match a sentence if this sentence starts with a certain word.

Example:

```
That shouldn't match.

This should match.
```

I came up with this regex: `.*(?!\b(That)\b)\.`

However, it's matching both sentences: https://regexr.com/5k7kp

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: How are you matching a sentence? Is it part of a larger text? A dot can appear in the middle of a sentence also like `Mr.`, `Sr.` etc

Answer (score 1):

The reason your expression matches everything is because the .* will consume the entire sentence up to the period. At that point, with only a period left, the negative look ahead assertion is satisfied - there is no "That" up ahead, just a lonely period.

One way around this is to use the start of string anchor:^

```
^(?!\bThat\b)(.*?\.)
```

Since there is no quantifier up front this will reject anything whose string has "That" immediately after the start of the string and will otherwise capture the string up to the first period.

But this only works if your sentence is actually at the start of the string. If you are also trying to capture sentences that might start in the middle of a string and you want to assume any period symbol indicates the start/stop of a sentence, you can do:

```
(?:^|\.\s*)(?!\bThat\b)(\S.*?)(?:$|(?=\.))
```

This wouldn't work properly for sentences that use period symbols for other reasons, for example sentences including numbers with decimal places, ellipses, or acronyms/abbreviations with periods. If you really want to handle all those cases you may be better off looking into a natural language processing solution.

Comment: You can simplify the first regex to '^(?!bThat\\b)'
There is no need for scanning (especially lazy matches) after the first term,

Comment: @TonyR correct if the goal is to only get a Boolean match decision. I assumed he wanted to capture the expression in the case of a match.

Comment: Thanks, but weird. `^(?!\bThat\b)(.*?\.)` is matching the sentence with the "That." Instead of matching the sentence with "This."

Comment: @alexchenco Works for me on that regexr site. If I change "A" to "That" and "B" to "This" or vice versa, then go under Tools > Details on bottom, it says Group 1 is sentence that doesn't start with "That".

Comment: @alexchenco See https://regexr.com/5k7oq    This shows the 2nd part of my answer. If you look at Tools > Details, Group 1 is always the correct "This" sentence.